# php $FILES is empty

Tags: php, jquery

i try to insert a row to db with php and jquery

I have this code

```
$.post('/json/management/AddArtistAjax', 
    {
       "artistName": $("#nameSurnameID").val()
            ,
            "Country": $("#country").val()
            ,
            "bDate" :  $("#demo1").val()
            ,
            "dDate" :  $("#demo2").val()
            ,
            "bio" : $("#bioID").val()


    },
    function(response){
            alert(response);
        });
```

I can send php side all of above.However, i cannot send files to php side

print_r($_FILES) array is empty why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot upload files like this via AJAX. If you do not need to support old browsers, you can use the [form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which supports AJAX file uploads and can even fallback to a hidden iframe for older browsers.